telethon , edit document filename?
this edits a the text of a message:
with TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.edit_message(
        entity=dest_id,
        message=msg_id,
        text=message_new,
        parse_mode='Markdown'
   )

according to official documentation 

attributes (list, optional): Optional attributes that override the
inferred ones, like DocumentAttributeFilename and so on.

so using
with TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.edit_message(
        entity=dest_id,
        message=msg_id,
        text=message_new,
        parse_mode='Markdown',
        attributes=[DocumentAttributeFilename(file_name="testtest.pdf")]
   )

does neither change the filename , nor raise an error.
any help to edit the filename would be appreciated
